# Is there any way to get usdt from Ropsten Testnet?

Tags: flutter, tether

I am making an app that can send and receive usdt using Flutter web3. I want to test on Ropsten network, but I want to know how to get usdt for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. You can get Ropsten Testnet usdt once a day from the site below.
https://testnet.help/en/ethfaucet/ropsten

Answer (score 1):

You could probably just copy and paste the code of the original and launch your own on ropsten.. wouldn't that be just as effective?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).